# Overriding admin template failing

Tags: magento-enterprise, template, overrides

I'm trying to modify an admin template by overriding it (instead of modifying the core template file directly).

So the way I understand it, I should just be able to copy a template file:
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/websites.phtml`

to:
`app/design/adminhtml/default/companyname/template/catalog/product/edit/websites.phtml`

Here's the tricky part: it works for just about every page except for the page I need it to work on. I'm trying to copy any of the templates used by Catalog->Products->->Custom Options

I can't seem to override any of those templates.
I've cleared every cache I own (even from my wallet just to be sure).
I've double checked all file names and paths.

I can't find error messages that would be helpful to give me a hit to what's going on, so I'm hoping somebody had run across this before or might be able to point me in the direction

At the very least at some hidden logs somewhere that might tell me what's going on?

Edit:
After digging into this more, we came up with an interesting find: the default theme is `customtheme` and the override template is `default`, only for this section. Everywhere else, default is `default` and override is `customtheme`.
We still have no idea why.

Comment: How is the customtheme value set in your system?  One possibility is this was done in a non-standard way, and it's being skipped for the product options theme.

Comment: Have you grepped your codebase for `customtheme`? Either in PHP or in XML, this *has* to be set somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've setup Magento's admin area to use `comapnyname`, as per [Ben's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14618/4), if you're still running into trouble, I'd jump right to the source.

The `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package` class is where Magento decides which files to use for a theme.  First the current theme is checked. If nothing's found there, then the `default` theme is checked.   That check happens here

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php
public function validateFile($file, array $params)
{
    $fileName = $this->_renderFilename($file, $params);
    $testFile = (empty($params['_relative']) ? '' : Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS) . $fileName;
    if (!file_exists($testFile)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $fileName;
}
```

I'd temporarily add some poor man's logging to this function to see the file's Magento is actually accepting or rejecting during a request.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php
public function validateFile($file, array $params)
{
    $fileName = $this->_renderFilename($file, $params);
    $testFile = (empty($params['_relative']) ? '' : Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS) . $fileName;
    if (!file_exists($testFile)) {
        file_put_contents('/tmp/design-files.log',"REJECT: $testFile\n",FILE_APPEND);
        return false;
    }
    file_put_contents('/tmp/design-files.log',"ACCEPT: $testFile\n",FILE_APPEND);        
    return $fileName;
}
```

My guess is you've got a subtle, hard to spot typo in one of your file paths.  Try

```
ls -l [filename]
```

with the results from the above logging.

**Update**: Based on the comments you've made, it sounds like you're working with a system where someone has customized things to work differently, and the  behavior is a side effect on that.

The two tacts I'd take on debugging this are

1. Figure out how your system sets the value for `customtheme`, and why this code isn't called when the page renders the Custom Options section
2. The custom options are rendered via ajax.  Normally, this is with a URL that looks like the following

   http://magento.example.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/options/id/166/key/2d18a7efe76c64829ba80b26aa153875/?isAjax=true

and the render is handled in the `optionsAction` method of

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
```

I'd look into if this is different on your system, either via a URL rewrite or a controller override of some kind.  This may explain why this particular URL is ignoring the custom theme.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, here's an interesting variable to add. We found out the default theme is `customtheme` and the override template is `default`, only for this section. Everywhere else, default is `default` and override is `customtheme`.

Comment: @FrancisLewis Just a guess, but are you confusing the frontend theme and adminhtml theme? Setting a custom theme for the frontend is done via the configuration UI, but this does not override the theme for the backend admin area.

Comment: I wish I were confusing the two, unfortunately I'm not.

Comment: @FrancisLewis Updated the answer with some possible theories.  You're almost certainly working with a system that's been customized to work differently in some way, and the behavior you're seeing is a side effect of that customization.  This means it'll be hard for a stranger on the internet to solve this problem for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh crud, changes were made to the Page file :( Yes, you're correct. Now I just have to track down what changes were made and why. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this you'd have to set the theme for the admin store, and this cannot be done via the Admin panel. Add the following to your *`app/etc/local.xml`* file:

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <template>companyname</template>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Comment: I did mention that it works everywhere else on the site, so unfortunately I can't be of more help on my question, but this doesn't point me in the right direction.

Comment: *"it works everywhere else on the site"* - I'm sure that it does. However, **the theme settings in the admin panel apply  to the frontend design area only**. This means that if you wish to have the same settings for the adminhtml design area, you have to add these settings manually to a configuration XML file (as my solution suggests.)

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the admin area, not the frontend. When I say "working everywhere else", that's everywhere in the admin section.

Comment: AH, I understand. Looking at your update, the custom theme has been implemented in a nonstandard/inappropriate way.